# How do I turn this program into a for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, printf

Hi all so I am trying to make a program that will print just as this one does:

```
public class L3Q5 // Class
{
  public static void main(String[] args) // Method: main
  {
    double x = 3.14159265358979;
    System.out.printf("%.1f %n", x);
    System.out.printf("%.2f %n", x);
    System.out.printf("%.3f %n", x);
    System.out.printf("%.4f %n", x);
    System.out.printf("%.5f %n", x);
    System.out.printf("%.6f %n", x);
    System.out.printf("%.7f %n", x);
    System.out.printf("%.8f %n", x);
    System.out.printf("%.9f %n", x);
    System.out.printf("%.10f %n", x);
    System.out.printf("%.11f %n", x);
    System.out.printf("%.12f %n", x);
    System.out.printf("%.13f %n", x);
    System.out.printf("%.14f %n", x);
  }
}
```

It prints like this:

```
3.14 
3.142 
3.1416 
3.14159 
3.141593 
3.1415927 
3.14159265 
3.141592654 
3.1415926536 
3.14159265359 
3.141592653590 
3.1415926535898 
3.14159265358979
```

Thus far this is what I have to make this work using a for loop and printf, but I'm a bit lost:

```
public class L3Q53 // Class
{
  public static void main(String[] args) // Method: main
  {
    double x = 3.14159265358979;
    for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
      System.out.printf("%.14f  %n", x);
    }
  }
}
```

What prints for this is just

```
3.14159265358979
3.14159265358979
3.14159265358979
3.14159265358979
3.14159265358979
3.14159265358979
3.14159265358979
3.14159265358979
3.14159265358979
3.14159265358979
3.14159265358979
3.14159265358979
```

Please help !!!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and [edit] your question accordingly.  See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1):

You are nearly there!

To turn stuff into for loops, you just need to notice patterns. You see how in each line this number increases by 1:

```
System.out.printf("%.1f %n", x);
                     ^
                     |
```

This number increases from 1 to 14.

What else increases by one each time? `i`, which increases from 1 to 12. That's not what we want because we want `i` to increase from 1 to 14, matching the number in the print statement. Therefore, you need to change your for loop to this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++) {
```

Now `i` is in sync with the number in the print statement. We can replace the number in the print statement with `i`:

```
    System.out.printf("%." + i + "f %n", x);
```

Answer (score 0):

One of tricky way to do it is as:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 14; i++) { // loop bounds to match your initial input 1 to 14 
    System.out.printf("%." + i +"f  %n", x); // just made that value i to be replaced in the string, before printf actually formats
}
```

Such that every iteration it transforms into something like:-

starting from `i=1`

```
=> System.out.printf("%." + "1" +"f  %n", x)
=> System.out.printf("%.1f  %n", x)
```

then for `i = 2`

```
=> System.out.printf("%." + "2" +"f  %n", x)
=> System.out.printf("%.2f  %n", x) ...and so on until i=14
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it for any number :

```
public static void main(String[] args) // Method: main
{
    double x = 3.14159265358979;
    int len = (x+"").length()-1;  //15
    for (int i = 1; i < len ; i++) {
      System.out.printf("%."+i+"f  %n", x);
}
```

**Note**: `(x+"").length();` will convert the double as string. So everything will be considered as a character(Even the `.` ). In your case it will give 16 as output. But, you only have 14 decimal values.